# Composer install into another directory for ONE project only

Tags: composer-php

After a "composer update", the dependencies are installed into a default directory, which is "vendor". Fine.

We can change it with the "vendor-dir" property if we wanna install these somewhere else.

For example in my `composer.json` :

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "plugins"
    }
}
```

works like a charm. Now, my dependencies are installed into the "plugins" directory. I tried it, it works perfectly.

==>

> What I wanna do is to change that but for ONE or TWO dependencies only, not for all of them. I didn't find anything usefull into the documentation. Do you have any suggestions please ?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md

Comment: Sounds like the correct answer. It works, thanks ! :)